# Migration Issues Updating MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, iis, azure

I've migrated a custom PHP application from a Linux VPS to Windows Azure Websites, and it appeared that the only issue was the replacement of PHP_mail with SendGrid. Currently this application is completely written from scratch without any framework and uses MySQL for data storage. When migrating the application, I made a .sql file and used MySQL Workbench to create the tables on my new database server.

The issue that I am finding is that I can log in with current users, however, I cannot update the tables successfully. There is no sign of the application adding another row. However, the application acts as if it was a success, and continues to a "success" page. However, no new session is created since there wasn't a user created.

The differences I can tell between the two databases is that the original table names had a capital letter while on the new db server, they are all lowercase table names.

I've tried changing the PHP version up and down from 5.4, and I've not made any modifications to the MySQL statements in the code.

Out of your experience, what can I do to help me find the problem?

EDIT:

Here's portion of the file that should be updating the data server:

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
if ($_SESSION['employerID']<>'') {
    header("Location: account_details.php");
}
if (($_POST["fname"]<>"") && ($_POST["email"]<>"")) {
    include ("config/config.php");  
    getConnect();
    $stmt = "insert into tblemployer (shortCode,company, fName, lName,email,address,city,state,zip,password) values ('".mysql_escape_string($_POST["shortCode"])."','".mysql_escape_string($_POST["company"])."','".mysql_escape_string($_POST["fname"])."','".mysql_escape_string($_POST["lname"])."','".mysql_escape_string($_POST["email"])."','".mysql_escape_string($_POST["address"])."','".mysql_escape_string($_POST["city"])."','".mysql_escape_string($_POST["state"])."','".mysql_escape_string($_POST["zip"])."','".md5($_POST["password"])."')";
    //echo $stmt;
    $query = mysql_query($stmt);

    $EID=mysql_insert_id();
    $_SESSION['employerID']=$EID;
    $_SESSION['userName']=$_POST["company"];
    $stmt = "insert into tblmembership (status, employerID, membershipID) values ('0','".$EID."','".mysql_escape_string($_POST["membership"])."')";
    //echo $stmt;
    $_SESSION['MID']=$_POST["membership"];
    $query = mysql_query($stmt);
    header( 'Location: corp_payment.php' ) ;

}   

?>
```

Comment: Just try changing letter case in ClearDB tables exactly like the old.

Comment: I'll see what happens, but why would case matter when you can retrieve information, but can't update it? EDIT: ClearDB is configured only to allow lower case table names.

Comment: I've not tried clearDB till now. Just a suggestion whether that makes any change!

Answer (score 0):

I clearly do not know why, but instead of Windows Azure I migrated the same code (without SendGrid) to OpenShift and it works as expected.

Is this an IIS rewrite problem?